# Partial differential equation. Initial Boundary Value Probem.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$u_{tt} − u_{xx} = 0    \quad 0 ≤ x < \infty, t ≥ 0 \\
u(x,0)= 0, \quad
u_t(x,0)= 0, \quad 
u(0,t)= t^2$$

find $u(x,t)$

My aproach was that $u(x,t) = 1/2 * f(x+t) + 1/2 f(x-t)$.
Where $f(x)$ is $t^2$.
$\Rightarrow u(x,t) = x^2 + t^2$
It seems to me that it is a weak solution which does not satisfy the starting point. But does it have to?

Please help with this problem.

Comment: I have not yet learned d'Alrmbert's formula. There should be an easier way to solve it. Would this solution work: for x > t  u(x,t) = 0, for x<t  u(x,t)= (t+x)^2 ?

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://www.math.toronto.edu/courses/apm346h1/20151/L6.html#sect-6.2) resource for a detailed derivation. Short answer for your problem with wavespeed $c=1$:
$$u(x, t) = \begin{cases} 0 & 0 \leq t \leq x \\ (t- x)^2 & 0 \leq x < t \end{cases}$$